# Error using composer in Windows

Tags: php, windows, composer-php

I need to use composer in my `Windows` installed xampp, php 5.4.7. everytime I run

```
$ php composer.phar install
```

I keep getting this error:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]  The
>   "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded:
>   failed to open stream: The system detected an invalid pointer
>   address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call.

What could be the issue
 ? Any help please.

Comment: No firewall or proxy restriction?

Comment: Firewall currently anabled, not sure about proxy :(